# Saving class issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities. First activity have button which one can open second activity.
In second activity i am doing some changes and i want to save that changes and when i will reatrt my app i want to click load button and have my changes back.

Already i tried some staffs which Gson and SharedPreferences but its doesnt work.

I have idea do save second class, but i dont really know if it is possible to do.

Can anyone tell where should i go to find some informations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do, but I'd suggest you to look at Serialization. It lets you saving Java objects and it's really simple. You can find some tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.